# How does the gradient operator pick up a minus sign when the reference frame is switched from one particle to another?

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces, potential-energy, differentiation

A potential between two particles, $i$ and $j$, is given as a function only of the separation distance,

$$V_{ij} = V_{ij}(|r_i − r_j|)$$

It should follow that the force by $j$ on $i$ is equal and opposite to that by $i$ on $j$,

$$F_{ji}  = − ∇_i V_{ij}  = + ∇_j V_{ij}  = − F_{ij}$$

What is the cause of the sign change when going from

$$− ∇_i V_{ij}$$  to $$ + ∇_j V_{ij}$$

Also, how can I show that

$$− ∇_i V_{ij}=(r_i-r_j)f$$

for some scalar $f$?

This shows that by defining a potential that is a function only of $|r_i − r_j|$ you are guaranteed that the resulting force satisfies the strong form of Newton's Third Law.

Comment: Just use the chain rule.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform That last $-1$ should be a $+1$.

Comment: @Jonas whoops yes, you're right. deleted. thank you.